# Two questions, One-staked coins stuck in comp mm wallet. Second question should my new mm wallet be showing seen.link as the only ipfs gateway?

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet

First thing, my mm wallet was stolen, yes personal stupidity and scammed by a supposedly helper. None the less they got $4500 worth of my cryptos from that wallet. They were not able to get a huge chunk of staked coins, not sure how or why but they didn’t, I want them but how? Second, I started two new mm wallets, one has multiple ipfs gateways on it and the other one that I had connected the compromised mew wallet to, in an attempt to secure the staked coins, only has one ipfs gateway, dweb.link. Why the difference? Which that does not show up on my other new wallet. Why do you think that is and is it safe to change that to something else? I was thinking that the dweb.link had something to do with the scammers sweeper bot. Pretty positive it has one because they had left $20 worth of eth in there for over three days and yesterday while looking through stuff to see if it would be possible to recover those staked coins safely, after about 15min of it being open and looking at it, the $20 worth of eth was sent out. I see ismael?!? I think it is, answers pretty frequently and honesty so plz help, if you can, no scams plz, I’ve been hit up by them like crazy since this has happened. Is there anyway to maybe block the scammers programming long enough to get some funds in and get those staked coins out? It’s amazing how many scammers are out there that can do this stuff but yet NO ONE can seem to do the opposite and help ppl get their coins back. Funny world huh?

Comment: That was supposed to say, should it only have dweb.link as the only ipfs gateway?

Comment: I don't know what the dweb.link is. MyCrypto provide a service to recover wallets affected by sweeper bots https://blog.mycrypto.com/how-to-beat-an-ethereum-based-sweeper-and-recover-your-assets/. You should contact them through their official channels.

Comment: Yeah, but who chooses which they will take?? Cuz I dunno if 10% would be worth them doing it and I really don’t have 250$ to pay them to get them out. I guess I could contact them and see, thanks!!!